# Oracle sql - concatenation is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am on 11.2.0.4 (migration to 19c will happen soon).

I want to run the following sql:

```
SELECT (select 'hello' from dual) c1 ||','||(select 'hello' from dual) c2
from dual
```

But it gives the error:

```
SQL>SELECT (select 'hello' from dual) c1 ||','||(select 'hello' from dual) c2
  2  from dual
  3  ;
SELECT (select 'hello' from dual) c1 ||','||(select 'hello' from dual) c2
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Can you please suggest how to fix it? Note that this is a "scaled down/converted" question for a large reporting sql and there is no freedom to change the query - I mean we do need to retain the two subqueries and join them by concatenating them.

Answer (score 3):

You have lingering `c1`s and `c2`s:

```
SELECT (select 'hello' from dual) ||','||(select 'hello' from dual)
from dual;
```

You might want `c2` if that is your intended column alias.